# Finding out if a folder has a sub folder, and if that sub fold has a sub folder and so on in Docslist

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I was wondering if it is possible to loop through a folder that contains other folders, and the other folders contain other folders, and so on in a dynamic fashion. I do not know how many sub folders have sub folders and would like to find out a way to check this with out hard coding. It's easy enough to go two levels down, but after that I am stumped on how to deal with the multi-branching and storing it in a way that I can manipulate it later. Any tips? In the end the folder structure will be used to create a dynamic Google site layout.

Here is an example of what I have so far:

```
function myFunction() {
 //Get the folder
 var topFolders = DocsList.getFolder('TestFolder');
 var lvlOneFolders = topFolders.getFolders();
 var num1Folders = lvlOneFolders.length;
 var someArray = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < num1Folders; i++){

 someArray[i] = lvlOneFolders[i].getFolders();
  }

 Logger.log(someArray);

}
```

Regards,

Shawn

```
function myFunctionTest() {
  var site = SitesApp.getSite('finance-in-motion.com', 'test-site');
  //Get the folder
  var rootFolder = DocsList.getFolder('TestFolder');
  var rootName = rootFolder.getName();
  var files = rootFolder.getFiles();
  var page;

  site.createWebPage(rootName, rootName,"<h1>What evs21</h1>");

  page = site.getChildByName(rootName);

  createFiles(page,files);

  recursTest(rootFolder);

  }

function recursTest (currentFolder){

  var curLength=currentFolder.getFolders().length;

   for(var i = curLength; i > 0; i --){

     var folders = currentFolder.getFolders();
     var parentName = currentFolder.getName();
     var foldername = folders[i-1].getName();
     var files = folders[i-1].getFiles();
     getSiteTest(foldername,parentName,files);

     if(folders[i-1].getFolders().length != 0){
       recursTest(folders[i-1]);
     }
   }


 }

 function getSiteTest(title,parent,files) {

   var site = SitesApp.getSite('finance-in-motion.com', 'test-site');

   var matches = site.search(parent);

   var page = matches[0];

   var child;

   //create the sibling page
   page.createWebPage(title, title,"<h1>What evs21</h1>");

   child = page.getChildByName(title);

   createFiles(child,files);

  }

 function createFiles(page,files){

   var name;

   if (files.length !=0){

      for (i in files){

         name = files[i].getName();
         page.createWebPage(name,name,"<h1>What evs21</h1>"); 

   }

         }


 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coincidentally I had a similar issue. I was collecting the folder names and numbers of subordinate folders and files. This may help .

```
    function listFolders() {
    var start = new Date();
    var topFolder = DocsList.getFolderById(TOP) ; // start point
    var foldersArray = [];
    foldersArray = getFolders(topFolder.getName(),topFolder,foldersArray);
    // do what you want with array of folder data
    }
    function getFolders(path, container,arrayin) {
    Logger.log(arrayin)

    var folders = container.getFolders(0, 300);
     var folderCount = folders.length;
         var fileCount = container.getFiles().length;
             arrayin.push([container.getId(),path,fileCount,folderCount]);
                 Logger.log(path + " #files= "+fileCount+ " #folders = "+folderCount);
    for (var i=0;i<folders.length;i++) {


    var thisFolder = folders[i].getName();
    var thisPath = path+"/"+thisFolder;



    getFolders(thisPath,folders[i],arrayin)
    }
return arrayin;
}
```

I am not the greatest javascript person so improvements to recursive stuff welcome

Comment: Thanks for the response. I figured out I needed to use recursion also. I will have to compare what you wrote to what I wrote. Your's looks a bit cleaner. What I am doing is getting all the folders/files and using the to create webpages with embedded links to the documents, since it is so hard to find stuff sometimes in the docs list. This way we will have a tree structure that creates a google site mirroring it, and it can be dynamically updated by anyone in the department.  Here is what I have so far:

Comment: I added the additional code to the original post. It still has a long way to go but it is working.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT :** using **DavidF better answer** I wrote this spreadsheet bound script that gets a nice looking presentation of results with columns for different file types and totals.

just to illustrate ;-)

**Edit2 :** *I replaced IDs with urls so I can directly go to that folder from the SS and added execution time display + a bit of formatting and formulas.
(note : container.getUrl() doesn't work correctly for the Root folder, that's why I replaced it with a direct url in an IF condition)*

here is the code :

```
function onOpen() {
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Update data", functionName: "listFolders"}
                     ];
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.addMenu("ListFolders",menuEntries);//
}

function listFolders() {
    var start = new Date();
    var dateString = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getTimeZone(), 'MMM-dd-yyyy');
    var topFolder = DocsList.getRootFolder() ; // start point
    var foldersArray = [];
    foldersArray = getFolders(topFolder.getName().replace('Root','MyDrive'),topFolder,foldersArray);
    foldersArray.unshift(['Folders url','path','# SubFolders','# Spreadsheets','# Docs','# Forms','# Drawings','# Presentations','# others',])
//    Logger.log(foldersArray)
    var l = foldersArray.length
    var duration = (new Date().getTime()-start.getTime())/1000;
    var durationString = Utilities.formatString("%01.1f", duration)
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().clear();
    sh.getRange(1,1,1,foldersArray[0].length).setBackground('#ffffaa').setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true).setFontWeight('bold');
    sh.getRange(1,1,l,foldersArray[0].length).setValues(foldersArray).setVerticalAlignment('middle').setWrap(false);  
    sh.getRange(l+1,2,1,foldersArray[0].length-1)
    .setFormulas([['="Situation on '+dateString+' ..............Total = "&SUM(C'+(l+1)+':I'+(l+1)+')','=SUM(C2:C'+l+')','=SUM(D2:D'+l+')','=SUM(E2:E'+l+')','=SUM(F2:F'+l+')','=SUM(G2:G'+l+')','=SUM(H2:H'+l+')','=SUM(I2:I'+l+')']])  
    .setBackground('#ffffaa').setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true).setFontWeight('bold').setVerticalAlignment('middle').setHorizontalAlignment('right');  
    sh.getRange(l+1,1).setFontColor('grey').setFontSize(9).setVerticalAlignment('middle').setHorizontalAlignment('center').setValue('execution time: '+durationString+' Seconds');
    sh.setFrozenRows(1);
}

function getFolders(path, container,arrayin) {
     var folders = container.getFolders(0, 300);
     var folderCount = folders.length;
         var ssCount = container.getFilesByType(DocsList.FileType.SPREADSHEET).length;
         var docCount = container.getFilesByType(DocsList.FileType.DOCUMENT).length;
         var formCount = container.getFilesByType(DocsList.FileType.FORM).length;
         var drawCount = container.getFilesByType(DocsList.FileType.DRAWING).length;
         var presCount = container.getFilesByType(DocsList.FileType.PRESENTATION).length;
         var otherCount = container.getFilesByType(DocsList.FileType.OTHER).length;

         if(path=='MyDrive'){arrayin.push(['https://drive.google.com/?hl=fr&tab=wo#my-drive',path,folderCount,ssCount,docCount,formCount,drawCount,presCount,otherCount])}
         else{arrayin.push([container.getUrl(),path,folderCount,ssCount,docCount,formCount,drawCount,presCount,otherCount])}

    for (var i=0;i<folders.length;i++) {
      var thisFolder = folders[i].getName();
      var thisPath = path+"/"+thisFolder;
      getFolders(thisPath,folders[i],arrayin)
      }
  return arrayin;
}
```

[image]

---

*previous answer:*

Here is a way to go.

It scans on 3 levels from root but you could easily enhance it to go deeper by following the same structure.

The result comes in an array with all folders represented in a classical way 
(folder/subfolder/subsubfolder) since I don't know how you imagine to make use of it.3

```
function folderTree() {
 var result = [] 
 var foldersL1 = DocsList.getRootFolder().getFolders()
   for(n=0;n<foldersL1.length;++n){
result.push(foldersL1[n].getName())
     var foldersL2 = foldersL1[n].getFolders()
       for(m=0;m<foldersL2.length;++m){
result.push(foldersL1[n].getName()+'/'+foldersL2[m].getName())       
         var foldersL3 = foldersL2[m].getFolders()
            for(o=0;o<foldersL3.length;++o){
result.push(foldersL1[n].getName()+'/'+foldersL2[m].getName()+'/'+foldersL3[o].getName()+'/')
            }
          }
        }
Logger.log(result)     
}
```