# List all files id inside a folder (no subfolders)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

How can I list in a spreadsheet all files id that are located inside a folder ? I have the folder id and the folder contains less than 100 files in total.

```
function list_all_files_inside_one_folder_without_subfolders(){
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0sdfsfd......sfdsdfTg'); // I change the folder ID  here 
// Logger.log('Folder name: ' + folder.getFiles());
sh.getRange(1,1,1,1).setValues('fileID');
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is quite simple if you read the documentation about how to write in a spreadsheet and how to get Drive's content.

Here is an example you can customize if you want :

```
function list_all_files_inside_one_folder_without_subfolders(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B3qSFd3iikE3TERRSHExa29SU3M'); // I change the folder ID  here 
  var list = [];
  list.push(['Name','ID','Size']);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    var row = []
    row.push(file.getName(),file.getId(),file.getSize())
    list.push(row);
  }
   sh.getRange(1,1,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. ;) I have spent 2 hours trying to find a way to do this. And finally I got lost ! Hence my simple question and your very helpful answer that will help other beginners in the future for sure. Thanks again. ;)

Comment: Thanks Serge, your script dropped the execution time from 30 min (maxed out) to 120 seconds. ;D

Comment: You just need to use another while loop on top of the file's one using DriveApp.getFolders()...

Comment: I added this above - while (files.hasNext()){....
  
  var subfolder = DriveApp.getFolders()
   while (subfolder.hasNext()){
    file = subfolder.next();
    var row = []
    row.push(file.getName(),file.getId(),file.getSize())
    list.push(row);
  }
  
It give me the sub folder ID's how do I get the file ID's within the sub folders.

Comment: Put it the the other way, loop through the folders and inside that loop look for the files and get their names and sizes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure of this, this is what I have and its only giving me all the folder ID's but not file IDs within the folders. -

while (subfolders.hasNext()){
    file = subfolders.next();
    var row = []
    row.push(file.getName(),file.getId(),file.getSize())
    list.push(row);
  
  
  while (files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    var row = []
    row.push(file.getName(),file.getId(),file.getSize())
    list.push(row);
  }
}

Comment: I'll write an update in another answer, it will be easier to read

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178743/discussion-between-user2240778-and-serge-insas).

Comment: @Sergeinsas Did you write up the solution with folders on another answer? Can you provide that link?

Comment: sorry for the late answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813879/finding-out-if-a-folder-has-a-sub-folder-and-if-that-sub-fold-has-a-sub-folder/15822032#15822032

Comment: @Sergeinsas Thank you. The linked solution lists only folders. I need a solution to do both files and folders. I think I will be posting a question for it.