# Backup Google Drive to .zip file with file conversion

Tags: linux, google-drive-api, applescript, google-docs

I keep going in circles on this topic, and can't find an automated method that works for mass data on a Google Drive. Here is the goal I'm looking to achieve:

My company uses an unlimited Google Drive to store shared documents, and we are looking to backup the contents automatically. But we can't have the data stored in a backup with google documents like ".gdoc" and ".gsheet"... we need to have the documents backed up in Microsoft/Open-Office format (".docx" and ".xlsx").

We currently use Google's Takeout page to zip all the contents of the Drive and save it on our Linux server (That has redundant storage). And it does zip and export the files to the correct formats.
Here: [https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout][1]

Now that works... but requires a bit of manual work on our part. And babysitting the zip, download and upload processes is becoming wasteful. I have searched and have read that the google API for Takeout is unavailable to use through gscript. So, that seems to be out of the question.

Using Google scripts, I have been able to convert single files.... but can't, for instance, convert a folder of ".gsheet" files to ".xlsx" format. Maybe copying and converting all the google files into a new folder on the drive could be possible. Having access to the drive and the converted "backup", we could then backup the collection of converted files via the server...

So here is the just of it all:

1. Can you mass-convert all of a google drive and/or a specific folder on the drive from ".gdoc" to ".docx", and ".gsheet" to ".xlsx". Can this be done with gscript?
2. If not able to via the method in question one, is anyone familiar with an Linux of Mac app that could do such a directory conversion? (Don't believe it because of googles proprietary file types)

I'm stuck in a bit of a hole, and any insight to this problem could help. I really wish Google would allow users to convert and export drive folders via a script selection.

Answer (score 0):

## #1) Can you mass-convert all of a google drive and/or a specific folder on the drive from ".gdoc" to ".docx", and ".gsheet" to ".xlsx". Can this be done with gscript?

You can try this:

[**How To Automaticlly Convert files in Google App Script**](http://scraping.pro/automaticly-converting-files-google-app-script/)

**Converting file in Google App Script into blob**

```
var documentId = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();        

function getBlob(documentId) {
 var file = Drive.Files.get(documentId);
 var url = file.exportLinks['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'];
 var oauthToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
   headers: {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oauthToken
   }
 });
 return response.getBlob();
}
```

**Saving file as docx in Drive**

```
function saveFile(blob) {
   var file = {
    title: 'Converted_into_MS_Word.docx',
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
  };
  file = Drive.Files.insert(file, blob);
  Logger.log('ID: %s, File size (bytes): %s', file.id, file.fileSize);
  return file;
}
```

## [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

> A time-driven trigger (also called a clock trigger) is similar to a cron job in Unix. Time-driven triggers let scripts execute at a particular time or on a recurring interval, as frequently as every minute or as infrequently as once per month. (Note that an add-on can use a time-driven trigger once per hour at most.) The time may be slightly randomized — for example, if you create a recurring 9 a.m. trigger, Apps Script chooses a time between 9 a.m. and 10 a.m., then keeps that timing consistent from day to day so that 24 hours elapse before the trigger fires again.

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  // Trigger every 6 hours.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .timeBased()
      .everyHours(6)
      .create();

  // Trigger every Monday at 09:00.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .timeBased()
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
      .atHour(9)
      .create();
}
```

Process:

1. [List all files id inside a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360214/list-all-files-id-inside-a-folder-no-subfolders)
2. Convert Files
3. Insert Code to a Time-driven Triggers

---

## 2) If not able to via the method in question one, is anyone familiar with an Linux of Mac app that could do such a directory conversion? (Don't believe it because of googles proprietary file types)

If you are want to save it locally try setting a cronjob and use [Download Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads)

> The Drive API allows you to download files that are stored in Google Drive. Also, you can download exported versions of Google Documents (Documents, Spreadsheets, Presentations, etc.) in formats that your app can handle. Drive also supports providing users direct access to a file via the URL in the `webViewLink` property.
>
> Depending on the type of download you'd like to perform — a file, a Google Document, or a content link — you'll use one of the following URLs:
>
> 1. Download a file — [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) with `alt=media` [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource)
> 2. Download and export a Google Doc — [files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export)
> 3. Link a user to a file — `webContentLink` from the [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource)

Sample Code :

```
$fileId = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M';
$content = $driveService->files->get($fileId, array(
  'alt' => 'media' ));
```

Hope this helps and answered all you questions

Comment: How could you, instead of getting the active document ID, get a list or array of all the files in the directory and convert them one by one biased on the original file type? I realize this may be advanced... I just can't express myself in this coding like I do in C# and C+ without knowledge.

Comment: Dose that answer you gave me in Part #1 refer to the code being linked with every single document? My true problem is mass-conversion. I have seen that file conversions are possible... But how would one specify, say a folder in the drive, and convert ALL of its contents. Regardless if it were 1 gsheet file, or 1000. It's not possible for our users (because many of the users are unqualified) to add gscript to the individual files they create, and for me to do so with hundreds of files.