# How To List Google Form Published URL With Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have some Google Form in my drive.
I want to list all that Google Form published Url in a spreadsheet.
For my reference, I use this post [LIST FILES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360214/list-all-files-id-inside-a-folder-no-subfolders) and try to get specific files type with [mime type](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type).
I'm having a hard time when it comes to specifying a list of publishedUrl.
I try to use  :

```
function listFormURL(){
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('MAPPING FORM')
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1Oj-o5jxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxJ3fcA'); 
var list = [];
  list.push(['Name','ID','Size']);
  
// I try to have four list :  list.push(['Name','ID','Size','URL']);    
// How to use  variable 'formUrl' below to get published URl list, not just 'Name','ID' and 'Size'
var formUrl = FormApp.getActiveForm().getPublishedUrl(); 


var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_FORMS);
while (files.hasNext()){
   file = files.next();
   var row = []
   row.push(file.getName(),file.getId(),file.getSize())
  list.push(row);
 }
  sh.getRange(1,1,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list);
 }
```

For now, I can get list 'Name','ID'and 'Size'  for every Google Form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

`FormApp.getActiveForm()` is used for the container-bound script of Google Form. In your situation, I think that `FormApp.openById(id)` will be useful.

#### Modified script:

```js
function listFormURL() {
  var folderId = "###"; // Please set your folder ID.

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_FORMS);
  var list = [['Name', 'ID', 'Size', 'URL']];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var id = file.getId();
    list.push([file.getName(), id, file.getSize(), FormApp.openById(id).getPublishedUrl()]);
  }

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('MAPPING FORM');
  sh.getRange(1, 1, list.length, list[0].length).setValues(list);
}
```

- When this script is run, Google Forms are retrieved just under the folder of `folderId`, and `'Name', 'ID', 'Size', 'URL'` are retrieved from each Google Form, and those values are put to the Spreadsheet.

#### Reference:

- [openById(id) of Class FormApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#openbyidid)

Comment: Like usually, you are my Hero @Tanaike.
Thanks for your help. 
Your modified Script Run Well.

Comment: @PSAB Plalangan Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.